# Create a control for Android AppWidget?

Tags: android, view, remoteview

You can see a list of `views` that are capable of `remote views`:

> absolutelayout-framelayout-linearlayout-relativelayout-analogclock-button-imagebutton-iamgeview-textview
>   and other controls.

My question is:

Is there any way to create a custom view that be capable of remoteviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to create a custom view that be capable of remoteviews?

If, by this, you mean "is there any way to create a custom `View` that a `RemoteViews` can use?", at best the only way that is possible is if both apps have that class. So, for example, if *you* wrote the home screen, and *you* wrote the app that is publishing an app widget, so *you* can arrange for your custom `View` to be in both apps, then *maybe* you can include that custom `View` in the layout used as the starting point for the `RemoteViews`. It's possible that the way `RemoteViews` inflates the layout that even this approach will not work, though.